# Should I get a habit of removing unused variables in R?

Tags: performance, r, variables, memory

Currently I'm working with relatively large data files, and my computer is not a super computer. I'm creating many subsets of these data sets temporarily and don't remove them from workspace. Obviously those are making a clutter of many variables. But, is there any effect of having many unused variables on performance of R? (i.e. does memory of computer fill at some point?)
When writing code should I start a habit of removing unused variables? Does it worth it?

```
x <- rnorm(1e8)
y <- mean(x)
# After this point I will not use x anymore, but I will use y
# Should I add following line to my code? or 
#   Maybe there will not be any performance lag if I skip the following line:
rm(x)
```

I don't want to add another line to my code. Instead of my code to seem cluttered I prefer my workspace to be cluttered (if there will be no performance improvement).

Comment: You can also use the `gc()` function to make R carry out garbage collection. I found that this is useful after removing a large object, as R seems to not immediately recover the memory after removing objects.

Comment: Minimizing the creation of intermediate objects is also good. Obviously, in your example, you could directly go to `y <- mean(rnorm(1e8))`. I find the piping of [magrittr](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) very helpful in combining steps that I previously would have saved to temp variables.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, having unused objects will affect your performance, since R stores all its objects in memry. Obviously small objects will have negligible impact, and you mostly need to remove only the really big ones (data frames with millions of rows, etc) but having an uncluttered workspace won't hurt anything.

The only risk is removing something that you need later. Even when using a repo, as suggested, breaking stuff accidentally is something you want to avoid.

One way to get around these issues is to make extensive use of `local`. When you do a computation that scatters around lots of temporary objects, you can wrap it inside a `local` call, which will effectively dispose of those objects for you afterward. No more having to clean up lots of `i`, `j`, `x`, `temp.var`, and whatnot.

```
local({
    x <- something
    for(i in seq_along(obj))
        temp <- some_unvectorised function(obj[[i]], x)
        for(j in 1:temp)
            temp2 <- some_other_unvectorised_function(temp, j)
    # x, i, j, temp, temp2 only exist for the duration of local(...)
})
```

Comment: @Hong Ooi, how can the question starter use this? Wouldn't both y and x ceaese to exist if they are placed in the `local` call?

Comment: @WetFeet I'm a decade late, but note that you can assign the return of local. i.e., `blah <- local({...})`. I use this when I only have one variable I want to modify globally. If you want to modify multiple variables globally, inside local as your last line you could return a list.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the above suggestions, for assisting beginners like me, I would like to list steps to check on R memory:

1. List the objects that are unused using `ls()`.
2. Check the objects of interest using `object.size("Object_name")`
3. Remove unused/unnecessary objects using `rm("Object_name")`
4. Use `gc()`
5. Check memory cleared using `memory.size()`

In case, you are using a new session, use `rm(list=ls())` followed by `gc()`.

If one feels that the habit of removing unused variables, can be dangerous, it is always a good practice to save the objects into R images occasionally.

Comment: Make a list of object sizes: sizes <- sapply( ls(), function(name) { object.size(get(name)) } );
Show the ten largest objects: sort(sizes,decreasing=T)[1:10]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a good programming practice to remove unused code, regardless of language.

It's also a good practice to use a version control system like Subversion or Git to track your change history.  If you do that you can remove code without fear, because it's always possible to roll back to earlier versions if you need to.

That's fundamental to professional coding.

Comment: OP's question is about the performance drag of unused variables, not unused code.

Comment: I understand what "Shoud I get a habit of removing unused variables in R?" means.  My point is that it should be done, but not because of the performance drag.

Answer (score 1):

Show distribution of the largest objects and return their names, based on @Peter Raynham:

```
memory.biggest.objects <- function(n=10) { # Show distribution of the largest objects and return their names
  Sizes.of.objects.in.mem <- sapply( ls( envir = .GlobalEnv), FUN = function(name) { object.size(get(name)) } );
  topX= sort(Sizes.of.objects.in.mem,decreasing=T)[1:n]

  Memorty.usage.stat =c(topX, 'Other' = sum(sort(Sizes.of.objects.in.mem,decreasing=T)[-(1:n)]))
  pie(Memorty.usage.stat, cex=.5, sub=make.names(date()))
  # wpie(Memorty.usage.stat, cex=.5 )
  # Use wpie if you have MarkdownReports, from https://github.com/vertesy/MarkdownReports
  print(topX)
  print("rm(list=c( 'objectA',  'objectB'))")
  # inline_vec.char(names(topX))
  # Use inline_vec.char if you have DataInCode, from https://github.com/vertesy/DataInCode
}
```