# Should I remove unnecessary variables from variable explorer?

Tags: python, performance, spyder

I have seen a [somewhat similar question for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218404/should-i-get-a-habit-of-removing-unused-variables-in-r) but I have not found any advice for Python and specifically with using the Spyder console.

Would it speed up program execution if I were to implement code into my script that filters out variables that are no longer needed from the variable explorer? I am not sure whether this is a good habit to develop.

For example, if I multi-file import using `pandas` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Desktop\files'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
```

and then, for example, join all files together into one dataframe:

```
li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

final = pd.concat(li, axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

Now I have my required dataframe `final` for further analysis, but my variable explorer is packed with variables no longer needed, namely `all_files`, `df`, `filename`, `li`, and `path`.

I could use `del` to remove specific variables mid-script, but would doing so improve the execution speed / efficiency of the script?

Comment: Deleting unused objects will reduce the memory use of the script, but probably not enough to worry about unless some of these are extremely large objects. Python does memory management for you, so it should mostly be doing sensible things

Comment: Even for R you should take the advice in the other thread with a grain of salt. From a code quality point of view, the best solution is to not *generate* unnecessary variables in the global scope in the first place. Removing them later is questionable, however. The proper solution is therefore encapsulation: decompose your work into sub-tasks and write functions for them.

Answer (score 0):

The one improvement you can consider is to use generator instead of `li` list:

```
def parts_generator():
    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
        yield df

final = pd.concat(parts_generator(), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

In such a way instead of allocating the whole list of dataframes (that can take substantial amount of memory) and then concatenating it creating an effective copy of the data from the list, you are allocating at most the memory for the final dataframe + memory for the largest of chunks.

On generators and the magical `yield` keyword you can [read here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).